# What exactly is a resource leak?

Tags: java.util.scanner

i am using the Scanner class, and keep coming across warnings, saying I should close a resource leak. It has not affected me before, so I have disregarded it. Will this cause any problems for me in the future? How do I close the Scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanner will not leak any resources, if the underlying object you use to initialise the scanner with is not leaking. You receive a compiler warning, since Scanner implements `Closable` and the interface specifies, that a (for lack of another word) *resource* must be closed after its use. Usually you will want to use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to automatically close the resource at the end of scope.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner("my input string")) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        process(scanner.next());
    }
}
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your scanner class:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.close(); //Here you're closing it
```

You can try using your scanner within a try/catch block to ensure that you will always close your scanner:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
   //Use your Scanner
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```